# Storage medium for the lifecycle of a single request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-persistence

Im sure there was a request-wide `object`-based storage medium, similar to `HttpContext.Current.Session`, that persisted globally just for the life of a single request, but I cannot for the life of me remember it.

Comment: Do you mean [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)? It's not request wide since it stores values across postbacks. Perhaps `Request.QueryString` or `Request.Params`, but this is also to maintain values across postbacks(and detecting user submit params)? Hmm, if you need to store values only for a single Request, why don't you simply use a class member of your page? It's lifetyme is exactly the lifetime of the Page.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, It was HttpContext.Items - its useful because it can be accessed from a static context

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I bet you're thinking of [HttpContext.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx).

> Gets a key/value collection that can be used to organize and share data between an IHttpModule interface and an IHttpHandler interface during an HTTP request.

Very useful for sharing state between HttpModules, HttpHandlers and pages from different parts of the request cycle.

More reading:

- [4Guys from Rolla - HttpContext.Items - a Per-Request Cache Store](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215202/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx)

Note that HttpContext.Items works for both ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.NET MVC but it there's a caveat when using both in the same web app. More about that in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134442/httpcontext-items-with-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

There's [TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata.aspx) in ASP.Net MVC. Items persisted there survive only from one request to the next. Ultimately, its storage is session state.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use `ViewData` (if its ASP.NET MVC) or ViewState (if its ASP.NET)?

Comment: Viewstate persists across postbacks, i.e. spans across multiple requests.