# HttpContext.Current returning null inside ErrorMail_Mailing handler (in Global.asax) for ELMAH

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah, httpcontext

We are using `ELMAH` for our `MVC asp.net` application.
When any `exception` occurs `ELMAH` sends error mail which has an event ErrorMail_Mailing,
I am writing handler for this event inside my Global.asax
and trying to read value from `HttpContext.Current.Items` variable but getting `null exception`.

Any work around please help.

I am applying what Scott is suggesting here:-
http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2011/01/06/customizing-elmah-s-error-emails.aspx
In global.asax.cs I am trying to write below event handler, where I want to configure subject line of error mail with something stored inside my `HttpContext.Current.Items`

```
  protected void ErrorMail_Mailing(object sender, Elmah.ErrorMailEventArgs e)
        {               
            if (HttpContext.Current.Items["CustomerName"] != null)
            {
                e.Mail.Subject = "Error came to / " + HttpContext.Current.Items["CustomerName"] + " / Error Type: " +
                                 e.Error.Type;
            }
        }
```

Comment: welcome to SO. :) you are trying to write handler inside Gloabal.asax? Please put some code.

Comment: I am trying to achieve same thing mentioned in the below blog :- http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2011/01/06/customizing-elmah-s-error-emails.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage Thanks, I am updating my question also.

Answer (score 0):

Within MVC it will depend on where you are setting the `HttpContext.Current.Items` value as to whether it will be available in the ErrorEmailEvent. Please reference the previous SO question - [HttpContext.Items with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134442/httpcontext-items-with-asp-net-mvc) for some guidance on setting this properly or an using alternate means like [creating your own ITempDataProvider](http://billrob.com/archive/2009/07/15/asp-net-mvc-without-sessionstate.aspx).