# access global.asax variable from mvc controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have some dummy data inside my helper class. I want to on every mvc4 application startup to call this static method which would generate necessary data.

so I was thinking to store that data in variable inside global.asax and use that variable from controllers

```
public class MvcApplication: ...
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        var dummyData = DummyData.GetData();
    }
}
```

But I cannot access this variable from my controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var data = MvcApplication// I cannot access to my dummyData variable
}
```

Comment: that is not a global variable.In c# there is no global variables and if you define a variable inside of a method you cannot access it from outside of that method.

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext.Items is accessible from global.asax, as well as from your controller. Please check this post for example:

[HttpContext.Items with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134442/httpcontext-items-with-asp-net-mvc)